# Clean way to implement async indexedDB in class

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have a class that loads indexedDB. Before methods in the class can access it, I need to have indexedDB loaded beforehand. Currently I'm using an `init()` method prior to any other method that does not have `this.db` initialized.

I'm looking for a cleaner way to implement what I have, which definitely isn't DRY. Essentially every method is currently implemented with the same code pattern below.

Problem points are:

1. The requirement of another method `init()` in order to properly
   handle the intialization of indexedDB.
2. The `if (!this.db) {` segment that ends up repeating itself later.

---

```
export default class Persist {
  constructor(storage) {
    if (storage) {
      this.storage = storage;
    }
    else {
      throw new Error('A storage object must be passed to new Persist()');
    }
  }

  // needed to ensure that indexedDB is initialized before other methods can access it.
  init () {
    // initialize indexedDB:
    const DBOpenRequest = this.storage.open('db', 1);

    DBOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded = () => {
      const db = DBOpenRequest.result;
      db.createObjectStore('db', { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      DBOpenRequest.onerror = event => {
        reject(event);
      };

      DBOpenRequest.onsuccess = event => {
        console.log(`IndexedDB successfully opened: ${event.target.result}`);
        resolve(event.result);
        this.db = DBOpenRequest.result;
      };
    });
  }

  toStorage(session) {
    if (!this.db) {
      return this.init().then(() => {
        const db = this.db;
        const tx = db.transaction('db', 'readwrite');
        const store = tx.objectStore('db');
        const putData = store.put(session.toJS());

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          putData.onsuccess = () => {
            resolve(putData.result);
          };

          putData.onerror = () => {
            reject(putData.error);
          };
        });
      });
    }

    // basically a repeat of above
    const db = this.db;
    const tx = db.transaction('db', 'readwrite');
    const store = tx.objectStore('db');
    const putData = store.put(session.toJS());

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      putData.onsuccess = () => {
        resolve(putData.result);
      };

      putData.onerror = () => {
        reject(putData.error);
      };
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

indexedDB provides asynchronous functions. `indexedDB.open` is an asynchronous function. It looks like you are trying to work with indexedDB in a non-asynchronous manner. Instead of storing the IDBDatabase variable as a property of the instance of your class, just return it as the resolve value and manage it external to the class.

```
function connect(name, version) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = indexedDB.open(name, version);
    request.onupgradeneeded = myUpgradeHandlerFunction;
    request.onsuccess = () => resolve(request.result);
    request.onerror = () => reject(request.error);
    request.onblocked = () => { console.log('blocked'); };
  });
}

function doStuffWithConn(conn, value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const tx = conn.transaction(...);
    const store = tx.objectStore(...);
    const request = store.put(value);
    request.onsuccess = () => resolve(request.result);
    request.onerror = () => reject(request.error);
  });
}

async function putValue(value) {
  let conn;
  try {
    conn = await connect(...);
    await doStuffWithConn(conn, value);
  } catch(exception) {
    console.error(exception);
  } finally {
    if(conn)
      conn.close();
  }
}
```